# display only single task(assigned to multiple users) in related list corresponding to an Object

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I want to assign a Single task to Multiple Users but want to display only single task in a related list corresponding to that Object.

At present If i am Assigning any task to Multiple Users, E.g- 50.User,It is creating 50 new new task corresponding to each 50 user in 50 new rows in a related list.It is becoming really conjusted to view.

Is there any way that Only Single Task would be created while assigning to Multiple Users and displayed Only Single Task to all Users in a related list to that Object.

Any kind of assistance would be really Appreciated.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The data model around Tasks does not support the idea of multiple users assigned to a single task. You might want to look at using Cases and Case Teams instead.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Thanks for the reply.
What I mean to say is In the Related List Of that Particular Object,It should show only single row displaying the task and which has been assigned to Multiple Users(Say 50) Instead of showing 50 different Rows.
Any More Suggestions would be really helpful to me?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the activity related list from the page layout, create a visualforce page holding a customized related list for activities. You'd need to develop a controller extension that fetches all your activities and then you could filter out the duplicates.